# Swapping HTML element with React.js through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Context: New to React. Wanting to build a versatile `<Wrapper />` component.

My question is: *"How do I change the HTML element that is rendered, based on a prop's value?"*

My component looks like the following:

```
const Wrapper = ({ elem = 'div', name, children }) => {
  const statement = `<${elem} className='oc-${name}-wrapper'>{children}</${elem}>`;
  return statement;
};
```

This quasi-solution just renders out the string. How might I write the above so that I could use the component with interchangeable elements like the following two examples, so that `<main>` and `<div>` would be implemented respectively? Currently the variables are successfully injected, but the code is rendered as a string, rather than executing.

```
// usage
<Wrapper elem="main" name="splash"><p>foo</p></Wrapper>
// output
<main class="oc-splash-wrapper"><p>foo</p></main>

// usage
<Wrapper name="content"><p>bar</p></Wrapper>
// output
<div class="oc-content-wrapper"><p>bar</p></div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to do but this way of doing stuff has a lot of security risks and is generally discouraged. Hence the name `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Render method should look like this

```js
class Wrapper  extends React.Component {
  render() {
   const CustomTag = (`${this.props.elem}` !== 'undefined')?`${this.props.elem}`: "div";
    const classIs = `os-${this.props.name}-wrapper`;
    return <CustomTag className={classIs}>{this.props.children}</CustomTag>
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML as `String` will not be rendered properly.
Try changing `Wrapper` function :

```
const Wrapper = ({ elem = 'div', name, children }) => {
  const statement = `<${elem} className='oc-${name}-wrapper'>{children}</${elem}>`;
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: statement  }} />;
};
```